# Release version of my Android app can not connect to my REST API server

Tags: android, rest, debugging, get, release

Currently I am developing an Android app using Android Studio IDE. App allows to send some GETs/POSTs to my REST API server e.g. to obtain database update.

Everything works like a charm on debug version of app. I am not using emulator but I tested debug .apt file on a few different devices and app is able to contact server to retrive and send informations.

The problem begins when I am installing release (signed) version of app. Then app cannot obtain data from server (POSTs are not working as well; tested on every device where debug version works fine).

1. Required permission is added before < application > tag to AndroidManifest.xml:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   ```
2. How I am sending GET request:

   ```
   public static void sendGet(final Context senderActivity, final String url, final IResponseValidator onResponse) {

   RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(senderActivity);

   StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(String response) {
           // Doing stuff on success
       }
   }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
       @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
           // Doing stuff on error
       }
   });

   stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
           100000,
           DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
           DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

   requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
   }
   ```
3. Example of sending GET request:

   ```
   Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {

       sendGet(activity, URL, responseValidator);  // calling sendGet method from previous point 

       while (wr.getResult() == null) { }  // 'Freezing' thread - waiting for response from server
                                           // I put this loop here because I don't want async call here
                                           // This is place where release version is stucking.
                                           // wr is object which is fulfilled in sendGet method when any response is obtained from server

       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               // Doing stuff depending on wr.getResult() value
           }
       });
   }
   });

   t.start();
   ```

The release version is stucking on while loop as I described in comments. Is anyone had problem similar to this? I would be grateful for any help, because I do not know where this problem comes from.

Regards,
Adam

Comment: If you are using `minifyEnabled true` in release you need to modify `proguard-rules.pro`

Comment: Thanks for response. I have minifyEnabled false in release section of my build.grade file

Comment: So maybe you are using some api keys (like sha), it is different for release and debug

Comment: are you able to add some logs on callback to see what is returning the server or maybe intercept de request with charles?.

Comment: what's the problem, does the request fail, or parsing? post logs of the issue